# Issue with Customer Order Collection Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, customer-collection

I have a problem with the default Magento core function. I really don't know whether it is a conflict with any other modules.

When we go to the customer menu in admin and select any customer from the list then click on the order tab in the customer details page. I can see that the loading image is rotating, there is no customer order I can see.

I have checked in the console there is a 500 internal server error. I have go to the class file path(vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Tab/Orders.php) and echo the SQL query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT `main_table`.`entity_id`, `main_table`.`increment_id`, `main_table`.`customer_id`, `main_table`.`created_at`, 
`main_table`.`grand_total`, `main_table`.`order_currency_code`, `main_table`.`store_id`, `main_table`.`billing_name`, 
`main_table`.`shipping_name`, `sales_order`.`coupon_code`, 
group_concat(DISTINCT `sales_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ", ") AS `sku`, 
group_concat(DISTINCT `sales_order_item`.name SEPARATOR ",\n") AS `name`, 
group_concat(DISTINCT `sales_order_item`.product_options SEPARATOR "|| ") AS `product_options`, 
`sales_order_item`.`qty_ordered`, `sales_order_item`.`qty_invoiced`, `sales_order_item`.`qty_shipped`, `sales_order_item`.`qty_canceled`, 
`sales_order_item`.`qty_refunded` 
FROM `sales_order_grid` AS `main_table` 
LEFT JOIN `sales_order` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_order.entity_id 
INNER JOIN `sales_order_item` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_order_item.order_id WHERE (`customer_id` = '73922') 
GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id`
```

The error code appears on PHPMyAdmin when I run the code

```
Error in the query (1052): Column 'customer_id' in where clause is ambiguous
```

This is the right SQL Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT `main_table`.*, `sales_order`.`coupon_code`, 
group_concat(DISTINCT `sales_order_item`.sku SEPARATOR ", ") AS `sku`, 
group_concat(DISTINCT `sales_order_item`.name SEPARATOR ",\n") AS `name`, 
group_concat(DISTINCT `sales_order_item`.product_options SEPARATOR "|| ") AS `product_options`, 
`sales_order_item`.`qty_ordered`, `sales_order_item`.`qty_invoiced`, `sales_order_item`.`qty_shipped`, 
`sales_order_item`.`qty_canceled`, `sales_order_item`.`qty_refunded` 
FROM `sales_order_grid` AS `main_table` 
LEFT JOIN `sales_order` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_order.entity_id 
INNER JOIN `sales_order_item` ON main_table.entity_id = sales_order_item.order_id 
WHERE (`main_table`.`customer_id` = '73922') 
GROUP BY `main_table`.`entity_id`, `sales_order_item`.`qty_ordered`, `sales_order_item`.`qty_invoiced`, `sales_order_item`.`qty_shipped`, 
`sales_order_item`.`qty_canceled`, `sales_order_item`.`qty_refunded`
```

How can I convert the order.php query to this one?

Comment: you must have added some column, my guess is you edited `collection` file.
let me know if you did. we can work on separate module for that

Comment: I didn't edit that file.

Comment: try disabling your custom modules. then check

Comment: Thank you Ali Hussain for your valuable comments. Let me check with your way.

Comment: When I disable and enable third-party modules. Then it showing the orders on the customer details page.  Thank you again.

Comment: See. There is some custom module which is over riding collection.

Comment: Okay, Have any easy way to find which module file is overriding the vendor-module?

Comment: search for di.xml files in your custom modules, and analyse each of them. 
Ambiguity would be solved by defining `customer_id` should be taken from main table, rather than joined tables. Once you will find the file simply do what I am doing in below answer

Comment: and don't forget to accept it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `addFilterToMap` for `customer_id` in the similar file, where joining happens with other tables.

```
class Collection extends OriginalCollection
{
  protected function _initSelect()
  {
    $this->addFilterToMap('customer_id', 'main_table.customer_id'); //add this in your similar function.
    return parent::_initSelect();
  }
```